# Django Serializer Method Field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Can't seem to find the right google search for this so here it goes:

I have a field in my serializer:

```
likescount = serializers.IntegerField(source='post.count', read_only=True)
```

which counts all the related field "post".

Now I want to use that field as part of my method:

```
def popularity(self, obj):
        like = self.likescount
            time = datetime.datetime.now()
            return like/time
```

Is this possible?

Comment: where is the second method from? (`popularity`), so where do you want to access the data?

Comment: Right inside the serializer class where "likescount" is in @DenisCornehl

Answer (score 93, accepted):

assuming `post.count` is being used to measure the number of likes on a post and you don't actually intend to divide an integer by a timestamp in your popularity method, then try this:

use a [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields#serializermethodfield)

```
likescount = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_popularity')

def popularity(self, obj):
    likes = obj.post.count
    time = #hours since created
    return likes / time if time > 0 else likes
```

however I would recommend making this a property in your model

in your model:

```
@property
def popularity(self):
    likes = self.post.count
    time = #hours since created
    return likes / time if time > 0 else likes
```

then use a generic [Field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields#field) to reference it in your serializer:

```
class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    popularity = serializers.Field(source='popularity')
```

Comment: Hey I implemented same but got following error:

`AssertionError at /api/recipes/2/`
`Field(read_only=True) should be ReadOnlyField`

Comment: Second option is the valid or better one if field is not read-only, it works with CharField or any type if it's known...

Comment: In the second case, since the variable name and the source are the same (popularity), you get an `AssertionError` because of the redundancy. In my case I used a ReadOnlyField, since its what I needed.

Comment: whats the `obj` when def a  SerializerMethodField ?

Comment: @244boy the `obj` argument represents the object being serialized. what that means is, if you are trying to serialize the `user` instance of the `User` model, that `user` instance will be available as obj.